# Magento - Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ampaction_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: php, magento

Whenever I open the configuration tab in Magento I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ampaction_Helper_Data' not found in /home/users/iftp/site.com/webshop/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

I have searched for a solution and read that it means Magento can't find a data.php file for a helper?

How can I fix this error?

-EDIT-

I have checked the files and it appears there is no folder called Ampaction under app/code/core/Mage.

Comment: Please post your config.xml

Comment: Try to look for the folder under app/code/local/...,app/code/community/..

Comment: I haven't touched any config.xml files. All I did was reinstall an extension and this error started popping up.

Comment: The folder does not appear to be in any folder under app/code where I imagine it should be.

Comment: ok i knew that. but post your Ampaction module config. in that somewhere you need to define full extention name instead of module="ampaction"

Comment: Funny thing is, it appears there is no Ampaction module.. It wasn't in the extension that I just installed either. I initially assumed since it's asking for Mage_Ampaction_Helper_data that it was maybe one of Magento's own modules but it doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: no its not default magento module. n its clearly mentioned that Mage_Ampaction_Helper_Data is missing

Comment: How can it look for a missing file if the actual module itself doesn't exist?

Comment: which extension you reinstall so error started popping up?

Comment: I reinstalled Mass Product Actions as it initially did work but later did not display the added actions. Its called Amasty/Paction. I just disabled Amasty/Paction and the error appears to be gone now..

Comment: Maybe you have an .modman forlder in the root of magento